# How to make CDash ignore (certain?) compiler warnings

Tags: cmake, cdash

I am using a [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) / [CDash](http://www.cdash.org) setup up, and am quite satisfied with it overall.

I am also a strong advocate of "builds should not generate warnings".

However, there is one compiler warning being generated on one specific platform that I absolutely, positively cannot do anything about (at this point of time, short of a complete refactoring of the code involved).

I can live with the yellow box on the CDash dashboard, but what's getting on my nerves is that CDash considers compiler warnings to be a **failure** of the build stage, sending me mails to that effect:

> FAILED (w=1): <...> - Linux - Nightly
>
> A submission to CDash for the project <...> has build warnings.
>
> Project: <...>
>
> Site: <...>
>
> Build Name: Linux
>
> Build Time: 2015-04-27T10:01:49 CEST
>
> Type: Nightly
>
> Warnings: 1

How could I set up CDash in a way that compiler warnings are *not* reported as failures?

I want to receive a "failure" warning only if something actually *failed*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section `Customizing CTest` on the [Testing with CTest](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest#Customizing_CTest) wiki page.

Short summary: In the outermost binary build directory create a file `CTestCustom.cmake` with the following contents:

```
# Additional regular expressions for warning exceptions during build process
list (APPEND CTEST_CUSTOM_WARNING_EXCEPTION "warning_to_ignore")
```

`warning_to_ignore` should be a regular expression matching the one compiler warning being generated on one specific platform that you absolutely, positively cannot do anything about.

Comment: That's it, thank you. The judges are still out on whether the warning is actually a compiler error. ;-)